# How to display properties not in common in PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

The Microsoft documentation shows that PropertyGrid only displays the properties that are common to all the objects that are in the array.

So I tried applying objects with different property values to the propertygrid.selectedobjects and find that the property in the propertygrid shows nothing (blank).

Is it possible to make the property shows something different (e.g. different options...) when the objects with different property values? Because it is ambiguous when the SelectedObjects with different property values or with the same property value which is blank(null).

Here is my code examples:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle[] rectangles = { new Rectangle(2, 2),new Rectangle(1, 2)};
    public Form1()
    {
        // The initial constructor code goes here.
        InitializeComponent();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObjects = rectangles;          
    }
}

public class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        Height = height;

        Width = width;
    }

    [Category("1. Property")]
    [DisplayName("1. Height")]
    public int? Height { get; set; } 

    [Category("1. Property")]
    [DisplayName("2. Width")]
    public int? Width { get; set; } 
}
```

After running above, I get the result:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6GZT.png)

But the result I expect is below (I use photoshop because I cannot achieve it):
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3V1S.png)

Sorry for I did not clarify my question.  Suppose there are two cases:

case 1:  the two selected objects have different "Height" values, namely one is a height of 2 and the other is 1, then we see a "blank value" for that property in the property grid.

case 2: the two selected objects have the same "Height" value: NULL, then samely, we see a "blank value" for that property in the property grid.

Is it possible to distinguish case 1 and case 2?

Thank in advance.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer this without seeing the classes and a code example of what you want and what is not working as expected. I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: code samples needed to answer such a question

Comment: Thanks for reminding.  I just adjust the problem to be more specific.

Comment: You need a custom `Editor` and/or a custom `TypeConverter`, depending on what kind of editor you want to show and whether editing of the property values is allowed. For example, decorate with `[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]` to show the standard `CollectionEditor` interface. Of course it won't show the properties values, since it doesn't know how to handle your type, but you can derive your custom Editor from this one and convert the objects. Or a custom `ExpandableObjectConverter`. Btw, your class object has a bad name and the constructor needs an overload.

Comment: You can also show any other Form object in your custom Editor: a Form you build to handle the presentation (and editing, eventually) of these values the way you want (i.e., build a specialized custom interface).

Comment: You question is not clear. Your comment… _”Because it is ambiguous when the SelectedObjects with different property values or with the same property value which is blank(null).”_ … does not make sense. Can you clarify what you mean here? If ALL the objects in the `PropertyGrid` share a “common” property, then that property will be displayed in the property grid. When the “values” of those object properties “differ”, then you will see a “blank value” for that property in the property grid. This is because there are “multiple different” values for that property.

Comment: That is why in the pictures, the “Height” property is “blank” since the two selected objects in the property grid have different “Height” values, namely one is a height of 2 and the other is 1. You can see the 2 in the “Width” property because both objects have the same “width” namely 2. Looking at the second picture it is not clear what you mean by “different options” for the “Height” property? Again, what you are asking does not make any sense. What “different options” are you wanting?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my expression errors. I edit the problem again to make it clearer.